# How to access a public, single google sheet without oauth2

Tags: gspread

I'm trying to log some data into a public sheet (accessible in incognito mode). I'm trying to avoid OAUTH2 as it seems I can only grant access to *all* my sheets and I'd like to avoid that. There are likely multiple users of the software and my google account contains some proprietary data.

I'm using Python3.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to create a "Service Account" (under credentials in the console) and share my sheet with the address in the JSON file containing the credentials.

Now I don't have to rely on OAUTH2 and granting access to all my sheets.